# Autoscroll implementation in a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, automation, uiwebview, scroll

I have an iOS app that displays content from a sqlite db in a UIWebView (theres a reason I am using the UIWebView over say a ScrollView, and it is for some CSS). I want to add a feature to my app that will make it easier to read from. I want to have a button, that initiates an autoscroll function where the UIWebView begins to scroll at a certain set speed when fired.

Pretty simple I imagine, I just have no clue of where to begin. Does anyone know of any tutorials about this topic? Can anyone give me some keywords that I can do research on to get a better understanding of how I need to set this up? Any help here is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`NSTimer`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) class to get a notification at certain interval and do animated scroll of the `UIWebView`.

Note that you will actually have to put the `UIWebView` in an `UIScrollView` in order to get the scrolling support. (The alternative is to make the `UIWebView` rectangle bigger than the viewport and animate its offset - which is what `UIScrollView` does, except better)

**Update**: To animate the offset of the `UIWebView` in the `UIScrollView`, use [`setContentOffset:animated:`](http://setContentOffset:animated). You will have to figure out the animation time interval, in order to set your `NSTimer` interval close to it, so that the scrolling looks smooth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What exactly do you mean by animating the offset? Thanks